# First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[0]. >>

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to do a numerical integration. The integration is within a function.

```
fxn2[k_] := 
 NIntegrate[
   r*BesselJ[0, k*r]*( 
     BesselJ[0, 1] - 
      1 + (BesselJ[1, 1]/
         BesselY[1, 1])*(2/Pi*Log[0.5*Exp[EulerGamma]*Sqrt[0.01/r]] - 
         BesselY[0, 1])), {r, 0, 0.01}] + 
  NIntegrate[
   r*BesselJ[0, k*r]*( 
     BesselJ[0, Sqrt[0.01/r]] - 1 + 
      BesselJ[1, 1]/
        BesselY[1, 1]*(2/Pi*Log[0.5*Exp[EulerGamma]*Sqrt[0.01/r]] - 
         BesselY[0, Sqrt[0.01/r]])), {r, 0.01, Infinity}]
```

But, whenever I start to plot `fxn2`, I get

> ```
> First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[0]. >>
> First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[1]. >>
> ```

May I know what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Might not be the only problem based on the error message, but here you need to use `k_?NumericQ` in place of `k_` to be able to use `fxn2` in other functions such as `Plot`.  Make sure you `Clear[fxn2]` before you re-define it.  http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs. I tried your suggestion, but the output message is still the same.

Comment: The message itself seems to be generated in th symbolic preprocessing part, you can avoid it iserting  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0} in the second integral. However the integral itself is diverging as was noted by 
@Marius Ladegård Meyer

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because of the integral extending to Infinity. If I simply do

```
NIntegrate[r*BesselJ[0, 10*r]*
(BesselJ[0, Sqrt[0.01/r]] - 1 + BesselJ[1, 1]/
BesselY[1, 1]*(2/Pi*Log[0.5*Exp[EulerGamma]*Sqrt[0.01/r]] - 
BesselY[0, Sqrt[0.01/r]])), {r, 0.01, 10000}]
```

I get the error

> NIntegrate::ncvb: "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {19.5412}. NIntegrate obtained -0.00084999 and 0.001570429957126261` for the integral and error estimates."

For some reason, this error message becomes what OP posted when the upper limit is raised to Infinity.

A workaround is to choose a large upper limit that is not Infinity (you are using `NIntegrate` anyway) and possibly increasing the number of allowed recursive refinements using the option `MaxRecursion -> number`. Using `MaxRecursion -> 20` and an upper limit of 10 000 on the integral gives me
[image: ListPlot]

for`ListPlot[Table[{k, fxn2[k]}, {k, 0.1, 10, 0.5}]]`